# MODULE_NOT_FOUND Error: Cannot find module 'express-jwt' on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, node-modules, modulenotfounderror

I have an angular application and I recently upgraded to node version 18.18.2 and although the frontend build fine, the backend gives an error when running on heroku:

```
Cannot find module 'express-jwt'
```

The web app runs fine when running locally but I run into this issue when trying to run it on heroku. Before upgrading node and some packages to make nodejs work, it ran fine on heroku as well.

When I run bash on heroku and navigate to the node modules, I do not see the express-jwt package but I do have that added in my package.json. Locally I do see the package.

The full error message is:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
 throw err;
 ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express-jwt'
Require stack:
 - /app/clover-server-backend/_helpers/jwt.js
 - /app/server.js
 at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
 at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
 at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
 at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/app/clover-server-backend/_helpers/jwt.js:1:20)
 at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
 at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
 at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
 at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
 at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
 at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:10:13)
 at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
 at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
 at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
 at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12) {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: [ '/app/clover-server-backend/_helpers/jwt.js', '/app/server.js' ]
 }
 
 Node.js v18.18.2
 State changed from starting to crashed
```

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "DineNGo",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "main": "server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --aot --configuration=${ENV}",
    "preinstall": "npm install --location=global @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli --legacy-peer-deps",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.19",
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.19",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "9.0.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^11.2.19",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.42",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.38",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.47",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.22",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.135",
    "@types/node": "^11.15.54",
    "@types/socket.io": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@types/w3c-web-usb": "^1.0.10",
    "@types/web-bluetooth": "0.0.4",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^11.1.0",
    "angular-cc-library": "^2.1.2",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.6.2",
    "angular-notifier": "^9.1.0",
    "angular-responsive-carousel": "^2.0.2",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^11.0.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.44.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "exec": "^0.2.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-jwt": "^7.7.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "got": "^11.8.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lz-string": "^1.5.0",
    "material-dashboard": "^2.1.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.19.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.4",
    "ng-apexcharts": "1.5.12",
    "ng-chartist": "^4.1.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
    "ng-socket-io": "^0.2.4",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.8.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-guided-tour": "^1.1.11",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^10.0.0",
    "openai": "^4.17.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "remote-pay-cloud": "4.1.1",
    "remote-pay-cloud-api": "4.0.4",
    "resize-base64": "^1.0.12",
    "rootpath": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "socket.io": "^4.6.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.6.2",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "ts-node": "6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "4.1.6",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^11.0.6",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "cypress": "^13.5.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "express-jwt": "^8.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng2-charts-schematics": "^0.1.7",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "swiper": "^6.8.4",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "source-map": "^0.8.0-beta.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.18.2",
    "npm": "9.8.1"
  }
}
```

my jwt.js file is:

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
const config = require('config');
const userService = require('../users/user.service');

module.exports = jwt;

function jwt() {
    const secret = (process.env.secret? process.env.secret : config.get('secret'));
    return expressJwt({ secret, isRevoked, algorithms: ['HS256'], cookies:false }).unless({
        path: [
            // public routes that don't require authentication
            '/api/users/authenticate',
            __dirname + '/dist/*'
        ]
    });
}

async function isRevoked(req, payload) {
    const user = await userService.getById(payload.sub);

    // revoke token if user no longer exists
    if (!user) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

my server.js file is:

```
require('rootpath')();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var exec = require('exec');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var exec = require('exec');
var mongoose1 = require('./clover-server-backend/_helpers/db');
const jwt = require('./clover-server-backend/_helpers/jwt');
const errorHandler = require('./clover-server-backend/_helpers/error-handler');
var http = require('http');

const config = require('config');
const { OpenAI } = require('openai');

global.openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: process.env.openAiKey ? process.env.openAiKey : config.get('openAiKey') })

var fs = require('fs');

var options = {

  key: fs.readFileSync('./src/assets/dine-n-go_com_key.txt'),

  cert: fs.readFileSync('./src/assets/dine-n-go.com.crt'),

  ca: fs.readFileSync ('./src/assets/dine-n-go.com.ca-bundle')

};
app.use(errorHandler);

//app.use(enforce.HTTPS());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/DineNGo', { dotfiles: 'allow' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use('/webhooks', require('./clover-server-backend/webhooks/webhooks.controller'));
app.use(cors());

// app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
//
//   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/DineNGo/index.html'));
// });
// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use('/api/*', jwt());
// api routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./clover-server-backend/users/users.controller'));
app.use('/api/temiDevices', require('./clover-server-backend/temiDevices/temiDevices.controller'));
app.use('/api/cloverApi', require('./clover-server-backend/cloverApi/cloverApi.controller'));
app.use('/api/cloverOrders', require('./clover-server-backend/cloverOrders/cloverOrders.controller'));
app.use('/api/categories', require('./clover-server-backend/categories/categories.controller'));
app.use('/api/items', require('./clover-server-backend/items/items.controller'));
app.use('/api/images', require('./clover-server-backend/images/images.controller'));
app.use('/api/cloverPay', require('./clover-server-backend/cloverPayment/cloverPayment.controller'));
app.use('/api/orderHistory', require('./clover-server-backend/orderHistory/orderHistory.controller'));
app.use('/api/bugs', require('./clover-server-backend/bug/bug.controller'));
app.use('/api/clientCredentials', require('./clover-server-backend/authentication/authentication.controller'));
app.use('/api/ratings', require('./clover-server-backend/ratings/ratings.controller'));
app.use('/api/rewards', require('./clover-server-backend/customer/customer.controller'));
app.use('/api/reports', require('./clover-server-backend/report/report.controller'));
app.use('/api/qrDevices', require('./clover-server-backend/qrDevices/QRDevice.controller'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/DineNGo/index.html'));
});
// global error handler
// start server
console.log('In server.js'); //*MES*
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? (process.env.PORT || 80) : 4000;
var server = http.createServer(options, app);

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("server starting on port : " + port)
});

// Socket Layer over Http Server
const socket = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: config.get('webSocketUrl'),
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});
// On every Client Connection
socket.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('Socket: client connected');
});

app.set('socketio', socket);
function execCallback(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (stdout) {
        console.log(stdout)
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(stderr)
    }
}
```

Comment: You've declared `express-jwt` as a _dev_ dependency. Assuming you need it at runtime, it should be a _regular_ dependency.

Comment: I added it to the dependency as well if you see my package.json file but still the same. I noted that when pruning the dependencies, nodejs removed express-jwt for some reason. setting NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false in heroku config solved the issue but how can I fix this for production in which NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION is true?

Comment: Don't include it in both places. It just belongs in _one_ section. Heroku installs dependencies and dev dependencies _and then [removes dev dependencies after the build is done](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation)_. If you leave it in dev dependencies, it will get removed.

Comment: Thanks, Removing it from dev dependency fixed it. Thanks again for the help